# XFCE keyboard shortcuts to navigate inside a window

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, navigation

I am wondering if it is possible in (Xubuntu XFCE) to enable keyboard shortcuts to navigate **inside** a window ?

I know about shortcuts to navigate through workspaces and windows, and to move around windows, but I cannot find shortcuts to access the different fields/buttons inside a given window, like holding ALT on Windows?

If it not directly available in XFCE, is there a package/software to implement this? or another graphical environment for Linux where such functionality is available?

Thanks

**Edit:** I am looking for a web browser access key-like feature but at the OS/graphical environment level and not at the application level.

**Edit2**: it seems that it is not possible at the OS level and should be parametrized at the application level if supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigation *inside* the windows is controlled by the application. For dialog boxes that use a common graphical toolkit, e.g. GTK2, GTK3, Qt, ... it is the graphical toolkit that defines the keyboard support for moving within the dialog.

So no, you cannot easily remap or define such keybindings yourself without going into the source code.

That said, there is usually some support for keyboard navigation build in into applications. There is a widely used convention that <kbd>F10</kbd> opens up the menu. Traditional horizontal menu bars can be accessed this way, but also through  "Alt" *accelerator keys*. For example, in Libreoffice and in Firefox, the "File" menu can be opened with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. Accelerator keys in menus are underlined when you press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Next to the accelerator keys, applications also provide *shortcut keys* to access specific functions. Under GTK2, you could dynamically reassign these. Under GTK3, you have to depend on whether the application supports reassigning these shortcut keys.

Finally, dialogs typically allow to navigate between different elements of the dialog using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys. Within elements, the arrow keys can be used. Drop down boxes can be opened with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, after which arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd> allows to select an item, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> allows to cancel the drop down. Dialog boxes also tend to provide alt accelerator keys that allows to quickly activate an item or select a button by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the underlined letter.

1. List item

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a software enabling this at the OS level.

Comment: It is unfortunatelly like this. Please consider accepting the answer you consider adequate, even if it is not what you hoped. I will add some comments on keyboard access that is implemented in GTK for the reference of future users.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the shortcuts you were mentioning, however I find these not satisfying at all hence my question.

Comment: I realized that, but I just wanted to add this info for the reference of future users.

Answer (score 0):

XFCE, allows users to create custom keyboard shortcuts, users can create custom shortcuts that do specific window actions, desktop actions, launch applications, or even run scripts.

On the XFCE desktop, there isn’t a custom section for keyboard shortcuts,custom keyboard shortcuts are added to the already existing list of shortcuts.

To create your custom keyboard shortcuts:

Open up the Settings application.

Click on Keyboard

Inside of the Keyboard app, look for the Add option at the bottom of the window and click on it with the mouse.

By clicking the Add button, a window labeled Shortcut Command will appear.

Find Command.

Next, to it, there’s a blank box where you can fill out your keyboard action.

In the box, write out the command for the application you’d like to launch with the keyboard shortcut.

If you’d like to run a script, write sh /path/to/script/.

If can’t figure out the command you’d like to write in the Command box.

Click Open to browse for the app on your Linux PC instead.

After filling out the command in the Command box, click OK to move on to the next page.

On the next page in the XFCE keyboard shortcut setup window, you’ll be asked to create the keyboard combination used to access the shortcut.

To set the combination, press the keys on the keyboard you’d like to use.

Be sure to repeat the custom keyboard shortcut process outlined above as desired.

There is no limit on XFCE for custom shortcuts.

When done, click Close.

Or Mouse keys is a feature of some graphical user interfaces that uses the keyboard as a pointing device.

Open the Activities overview and start typing Accessibility.

You can access the Activities overview by pressing on it, by moving your mouse pointer against the top-left corner of the screen, by using Ctrl+Alt+Tab followed by Enter, or by using the Super key.

Click Accessibility to open the panel.

Use the up and down arrow keys to select Mouse Keys in the Pointing & Clicking section, then press Enter to switch the Mouse Keys switch to on.

Make sure that Num Lock is turned off. You will now be able to move the mouse pointer using the keypad.

The keypad is a set of numerical buttons on your keyboard, usually arranged into a square grid.

If you have a keyboard without a keypad (such as a laptop keyboard), you may need to hold down the function (Fn) key and use certain other keys on your keyboard as a keypad.

If you use this feature often on a laptop, you can purchase external USB or Bluetooth numeric keypads.

Each number on the keypad corresponds to a direction.

For example, pressing 8 will move the pointer upwards and pressing 2 will move it downwards.

Press the 5 key to click once with the mouse, or quickly press it twice to double-click.

Most keyboards have a special key which allows you to right-click, sometimes called the Menu key. Note, however, that this key responds to where your keyboard focus is, not where your mouse pointer is.

See Simulate a right mouse click for information on how to right-click by holding down 5 or the left mouse button.

If you want to use the keypad to type numbers while mouse keys is enabled, turn Num Lock on.

The mouse cannot be controlled with the keypad when Num Lock is turned on, though.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html.en

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the custom keyboard shortcut definition in XFCE, I precisely don't which command to use to enable the feature that I am describing.
And regarding the mouse control from the keyboard, it is not what I am looking for.